# Maximum Likelihood Estimation (absolute value)

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, median

Im currently struggling on a problem.
Let X1, . . . , Xn be a random sample of a random variable that has a pdf: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-\left |x-\theta   \right |}, \infty <x<\infty $$
**And I want to find the MLE for θ!**
So to solve this I start with finding the L(θ) for both when x>θ and when x<θ. For the following problem they will give the same answer so I derive L(θ) for only the first one, which gives us L(θ)=$2^{-n}\cdot e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n}-x_{k}+\theta }$. I then take the derivative with respect to θ of L(θ) and set it equal to zero. I get that $θ=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ which is the sample **mean**. But according to the solution from my professor the answer should be that the MLE of θ is the **median** of the sample. So I guess I have done something wrong. I would really appreciate some help in how I should think. Thanks!

Comment: You want to minimize $\lvert x_1-\theta\rvert +\lvert x_2-\theta\rvert +\dots$. It is well known that the median minimizes the $L^1$ distance.

Comment: You should have $L(\theta)= 2^{-n}\cdot e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} -|x_{k}-\theta|}$.  This does not have a derivative when $\theta$ is equal to any of the $x_k$. (I think that when the $x_k$ are distinct and $k$ is odd then it does not have a zero-derivative anywhere)

Comment: Okay I think I understand now! Thank you.